# Сколько осталось до конца даты

Tags: python, dataframe

Как узнать, сколько лет и месяцев осталось до конца датафрейма с начала даты data_start?

```
data_start = '1995-01-01'

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

1989-07-21
1989-07-22
1989-07-23
1989-07-24
1989-07-27
1989-07-28
1989-07-29
1989-07-30
...
2020-11-19
2020-11-20
```

Лет 15,
Месяцев 179.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data_start = '1995-01-01'

date_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_start, "%Y-%m-%d")

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

years = relativedelta(data.iloc[-1]["Date"], date_).years
months = relativedelta(data.iloc[-1]["Date"], date_).months + years*12
print(f"Лет: {years}")
print(f"Месяцев: {months}")
```

```
 Лет: 25
 Месяцев: 310
```